# mongoimport ignore _id key (E11000 duplicate key error index)

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport

Let's say I have the following two JSONs, and I'd like to import them to the same collection without merging or updating the existing documents. Is there a way, to ignore the existing _id keys during import and end up with a single collection containing all the 6 documents of the example below?

The old _id properties have no relevance whatsoever. I could rename/remove them from the source files, I'm just curious if there is a way to do this during import.

```
coll1.json:
{"_id":1,"a":1}
{"_id":2,"a":2}
{"_id":3,"a":3}
```

and

```
coll2.json:
{"_id":1,"a":4}
{"_id":2,"a":5}
{"_id":3,"a":6}
```

If I simply import them, with `mongoimport --db imp --collection imp --file coll2.json` I'm getting E11000 duplicate key error.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to overwrite the document import by using following command

```
mongoimport --db imp --collection imp  --mode upsert --file coll2.json
```

In mongodb **_id** field is by default unique so you cant have _id with same value like you had in your case

```
coll1.json:
{"_id":1,"a":1} // _id is same as document below
{"_id":2,"a":2}
{"_id":3,"a":3}

coll2.json:
{"_id":1,"a":4} // {"_id":1,"a":1}
{"_id":2,"a":5}
{"_id":3,"a":6}
```

What you can do in this case is Change the name of key from _id to id which will allow you to have more then one document with same value of id.

```
coll1.json:
    {"idField":1,"a":1} 
    {"idField":2,"a":2}
    {"idField":3,"a":3}

    coll2.json:
    {"idField":1,"a":4} 
    {"idField":2,"a":5}
    {"idField":3,"a":6}
```

Comment: The old _id properties have no relevance whatsoever. I could rename/remove them from the source files, I'm just curious if there is a way to import the data to Mongo without keeping the original _ids.

Comment: hey I have edited the answer have a look on it you just need to add  --mode upsert in your import query to do this.

Comment: upsert coll2 would overwrite the documents from coll1. I need to keep and import them all.